# How do I remove all field codes from a Word document

Tags: microsoft-word, field-codes

Field codes often find its way into Word documents (e.g. graph references, citations etc.). When we want to submit the completed document to someone else, often it would be necessary to remove field codes to prevent them from showing up as errors on a PC with a different set-up as yours.

How do I remove all field codes from a Word document?

Answer (score 7):

1. Select whole document by `Ctrl` + `A`
2. `Ctrl` + `6`

Comment: `Alt` + `A` ? Or do you mean `STRG` + `A`?

Comment: `Ctrl` is the same as `Strg` . It is not the `Alt`  key.

Answer (score 2):

You can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select all, then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> to remove all the field codes

This will replace them with the text they contained.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> didn't work for me, this may be a Word version issue.

Comment: This is what worked for me on Word 2016